# Cypher query for all nodes that lack a certain property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a [neo4j](http://neo4j.com) database with some data in it. Most of the nodes have a `name` property, but not all of them; I'd like to construct a Cypher query to match and return all those that don't.

I've tried all the following, but all of them give 0 results:

```
MATCH (n { name: NULL }) RETURN n
MATCH (n { name: null }) RETURN n
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name = NULL RETURN n
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name = null RETURN n
```

However, I have at least one node with no `name` property specified, which I can prove either through

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 4 RETURN n
```

and examining the node in the results view, or by noting that

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 4 RETURN n.name
```

returns `null`.

**How do I match *all* the nodes that *don't*  have a `name` property?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `HAS` function:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE not has(n.name) RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks - this does exactly what I was after!

Comment: FYI: "The HAS() function has been superseded by EXISTS() and has been removed." https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher

Answer (score 9):

`EXISTS()` has replaced `HAS()` so your query would now look like:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT EXISTS(n.name) RETURN n
```

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/